# Puppeteer click on div is executed but does not open div in browser

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, puppeteer

I would like to open a div container with Puppeteer. The click event fires, but the div does not open.

This works in Chromes developer tools to open the div container.
`document.documentElement.querySelectorAll("div[role=feed]").item(0).childNodes[5].querySelector("div[dir=auto]").querySelector("div[role=button]").click()`

So I used the query above to implement it in my Puppeteer tool. To check if the click was executed, I added an event listener. The click is executed successfully and the event of the click listener is fired, but the div container does not open in the browser.

```
let a = (new JSDOM(feed)).window.document.documentElement.querySelectorAll("div[role=feed]").item(0).childNodes[currentPostCount + 1]
let b = a.querySelector("div[dir=auto]")
let c = b.querySelector("div[role=button]")
c.addEventListener('click', function () {
  console.log('It was clicked!');
})
c.click()
```

```
const app = express()
const port = 3000
app.listen(port, async () => {
    await initBrowser()
    return console.log(`Express is listening at http://localhost:${port}`)
})

const initBrowser = async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        defaultViewport: null,
        headless: false
    })

    const incognitoContext = await browser.createIncognitoBrowserContext();
    page = await incognitoContext.newPage();
    await page.setUserAgent('Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3419.0 Safari/537.36');

    await page.viewport({
        width: 1920,
        height: 1080
    })

    await page.goto(url)

    await humanizerType('input[id="email"]', profile['profiles'][0]["email"])
    await humanizerType('input[id="pass"]', profile['profiles'][0]["password"])
    await page.waitForSelector('button[name="login"]')
    await page.click('button[name="login"]')

    // Start group automation
    await page.waitForNavigation()

    for (const groupId of profile.profiles[0].groupIds) {

        await page.goto(`${groupId}`)

        let postCount = await page.$eval('div[role=feed]', el => el.childElementCount)
        while (postCount < toObservedGroupPosts) {
            await page.evaluate(_ => {
                window.scrollBy(0, 5000);
            });
            postCount = await page.$eval('div[role=feed]', el => el.childElementCount)
        }

        const feed = await page.$eval('div[role=feed]', el => el.outerHTML)

        let commentedPosts = 0
        let currentPostCount = 0

        while (commentedPosts < writeDreamInterpretationsPerGroup && currentPostCount < postCount) {

            log.meta.date = new Date().toISOString()
            log.meta.isRelevant = false
            log.meta.isError = false

            let post = (new JSDOM(feed)).window.document.documentElement.querySelectorAll("div[role=feed]").item(0).childNodes[currentPostCount + 1]
            log.post.groupId = groupId

            let content = post.querySelector("div[dir=auto][class]").textContent.toLowerCase()

            /** START CLICK ACTION **/
            if (content.includes('mehr anzeigen')) {
                let a = (new JSDOM(feed)).window.document.documentElement.querySelectorAll("div[role=feed]").item(0).childNodes[currentPostCount + 1]
                let b = a.querySelector("div[dir=auto]")
                let c = b.querySelector("div[role=button]")
                c.addEventListener('click', function () {
                    console.log('It was clicked!');
                })
                c.click()
            }
            /** END CLICK ACTION **/

            log.post.content = content

            let user = post.querySelector("h2 span a").textContent
            log.post.user = user

            let date = `${new Date().getFullYear()}-${formatMonth(post.textContent.match(dateRegex)[0].match(monthRegex)[0])}-${post.textContent.match(dateRegex)[0].match(dayRegex)[0]}T${post.textContent.match(timeRegex)[0]}:00.000Z`
            log.post.postedAt = date

            // Perform keyword list
            for (const keyword of keywords.whitelist) {
                if (content.includes(keyword)) {
                    log.post.keywordsInWhitelist.push(keyword)
                    log.meta.isRelevant = true
                }
            }

            for (const keyword of keywords.blacklist) {
                if (content.includes(keyword)) {
                    log.post.keywordsInBlacklist.push(keyword)
                    log.meta.isRelevant = false
                }
            }

                commentedPosts++;
            }

            currentPostCount++;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: could you share how you implemented the above script in your puppeteer tool? may it be an async-await issue, but we can’t tell without seeing where and how you execute it in puppeteer.

Comment: @theDavidBarton thank you. I have added the implementation, I would be very happy if you help me.

Comment: it seems you stepped out of puppeteer's evaluation scope before the `while` loop. you cannot use client-side JavaScript like `querySelector()` in Node.Js. you should wrap everything within the while loop into one `page.evaluate(() => { /* your code goes here */ })`. if you can solve it with this hint feel free to post your solution once you've resolved it, but if you need further help how to re-compose it with evaluate, i will try to give a hand later.

Comment: Thanks, I will try it and give feedback tomorrow. Would it be possible to avoid the client side code and create it with `page.click()`? Is it possible to use something like `childNodes[currentPostCount + 1]` with `page.click()`?

Comment: e.g. I need to click this selector `document.documentElement.querySelectorAll("div[role=feed]").item(0).childNodes[6].querySelector("div[dir=auto]").querySelector("div[role=button]")`

Comment: it seems to me all your script inside the `while` could be executed with puppeteer API methods (a bit long script, so I may overlook and be mistaken). but in general, it is not an anti-pattern to execute bigger bunches of JavaScript in a puppeteer script: you just need to wrap it correctly :)

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments below I used `page.evaluate` to run client-side JS. It took me some time to figure out how to submit parameters. See below:

```
await page.evaluate((currentPostCount) => {
  let a = document.documentElement.querySelectorAll("div[role=feed]").item(0).childNodes[currentPostCount + 1]
  let b = a.querySelector("div[data-visualcompletion=ignore-dynamic]").firstChild.firstChild
  b.querySelectorAll("div:nth-child(1)").item(0).childNodes[1].querySelector("div[data-visualcompletion]").click()
}, currentPostCount);
```